# Which ARIMA Model to use based on the ACF and PACF visuals of my data using fpp3 package

Tags: r, forecasting, arima

I am trying to create an arima forecast model using fpp3 package in R. I am trying to use an ARIMA model, it looks like my data has some season component, but hard to tell. Here are the ACF + PACF visuals of the 3 groups - (A, B,C). I am trying to forecast number of clients in each group for the next 1 year and so, I am using the fpp3 package in r

[image]

[image]

Using the fpp3 package, I ran differencing tests as well to find out the d value of the pdq, and this is what I got:

```
data  %>%
   features(volume, unitroot_kpss)
   A tibble: 3 × 3
   provider_group          kpss_stat kpss_pvalue
  <chr>                  <dbl>       <dbl>
1 A                     0.774      0.01  
2 B                     0.549      0.0307
3 C                     0.772      0.01  

data %>%
   features(volume, unitroot_ndiffs)
   A tibble: 3 × 2
  provider_group          ndiffs
  <chr>              <int>
1 A                     1
2 B                     1
3 C                     1
```

I also used the nsdiffs function and got this value below, I am wondering does that mean that my data has seasonal component and that I need to take 2 differences for the model?

```
data %>%
   features(volume, unitroot_nsdiffs)
   A tibble: 3 × 2
  provider_group          nsdiffs
  <chr>               <int>
1 A                       2
2 B                       2
3 C                       2
```

I have also used the following function in each provider group to see if the seasonal component can be determined:

```
data %>%
  filter(provider_group =="B") %>%
  gg_tsdisplay(difference(volume, 12) %>% difference(), plot_type = "partial", lag = 24)
```

[image]

The other two groups did not have the lags go outside the blue dots only group b had 2 significant lags in ACF and PACF

Based on the visuals, this is how I wrote my model:

[image]

These are all based on my guess based on the visuals that I have generated. I know that I only have 2 years worth of data to really see the seasonal component but based on visual, it looks like seasonality could exist. Which is why, I would really appreciate it if someone could please help me write my arima model and help figure out the best pdq and PDQ values based on my data above.